# What might cause a NullPointerException when running Camera.release()?

Tags: android

Android 2.1 - I'm trying to work with the Camera via a widget.

My widget sets up and calls mCamera = Camera.open();, I can do everything with the camera, but when I go to release the camera via a 2nd widget click, mCamera.release(); throws a NullPointerException.

How much I find out why that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that mCamera isn't null?

That's the only reason I can imagine why that specific statement would return a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what it was.  I was inadvertently re-initializing mCamera every time the Service ran.   Put it further up stream and now it works wonderfully!

Comment: Was just typing out what to look for, but I'm much happier that you found it yourself. Learning is always great :D